# How does one go about designing a substrate heater for PVD? I need to design one that can go till 1000 C in Oxygen.

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics

Can I just use a Kanthal wire and make a pattern on a ceramic base? Wouldn't such an exposed element get shorted when I use substrates like Silicon? But wouldn't a layer of ceramic on top of the element both reduce the maximum attainable temperature and also increase the thermal mass?

Comment: Metal wires and oxygen don't generally get along. I would think more along the lines of a ceramic susceptor design, commonly used in semiconductor processing. These can certainly go to 1000C. OR radiant heating with a quartz lamp is fairly cheap, but harder to control.  Please note that the rest of your system must use oxygen rated components!